# Comparar variáveis com valores de uma tabela SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Eu tenho 1 tabela com 2 colunas (***Code*** e ***Value***). Estou a escrever um código em C# e tenho uma variável ***taxpercentage***. O que eu preciso é de retornar o valor da coluna ***Code***, quando a variável ***taxpercentage*** for igual ao valor da coluna ***Value***. Tenho ler a coluna ***Value*** e quando encontrar correspondência, retorno o ***Code***.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo:
Se a minha variável for 23.00, quero retornar o 6 !
Eu experimentei este código, mas não funciona:

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Value, Code FROM IVA", conn);
SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();

if(rd.HasRows)
{
   while (rd.Read())
   {
      if (taxpercentage == rd["Value"].ToString())
      {
         codeiva = rd["Code"].ToString();
         Console.WriteLine(codeiva);
      }
   }
}
conn.Close();
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer ?

Comment: Como você está atribuindo valor na variável `taxpercentage`?

Comment: Coloca a declaração da variável `taxpercentage`

Comment: A variável taxpercentage é um valor que eu estou a ler de um ficheiro xml, assim:   XmlNodeList taxlist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Tax");
                foreach (XmlNode xn1 in taxlist)
                {
                    string taxpercentage = xn1["TaxPercentage"].InnerText;
                }

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que execute a pesquisa diretamente no servidor de banco de dados, para evitar que todo o conteúdo da tabela IVA trafegue pela rede.

```
SELECT Code from IVA where Value = @taxpercentage
```

Desta forma somente trafegará pela rede as linhas que atendam ao requisito. E o processamento da pesquisa ocorrerá no servidor de banco de dados.

Comment: e depois como é que eu posso atribuir o valor que receber a uma variável ? Eu recebo o valor do Code respetivo e quero pôr esse valor numa variável chamada "codeiva"